# How to stop Chrome and Firefox from sorting sessionStorage by key alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have a JS script that adds (sessionStorage.setItem()) and removes (sessionStorage.removeItem()) items to sessionStorage. It works on the principle that adding an item would append it to the end of the sessionStorage array. It works as intended in Edge, but when testing in Chrome and Firefox, after adding an item to sessionStorage, sessionStorage gets reordered by key alphabetically, meaning that the last item added does not sit at the end of the array, which ruins the whole script. How do I prevent this?
This is the function that adds items to sessionStorage:

```
function addToCompareList(productName, productID, productHref) {
        var existsInCompare = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
            if(sessionStorage.key(i) == productName) {
                existsInCompare = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!existsInCompare) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(productName, productID + ',' + productHref);
        }
        //item limit should be 4, so if storage exceeds limit, remove oldest item. This is the part that becomes faulty in some browsers
        if(sessionStorage.length > 4) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem(sessionStorage.key(0));
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the function that adds items to sessionStorage.

After an item is added, looping through session storage and console.log()-ing every item works differently in different browsers: in Edge, items get logged in the order by which they were added, in Chrome and Firefox they get logged alphabetically, which means that the commented section of the code cannot work as intended.

Comment: sessionStorage is **not** an array ... and what makes you think anything is in any particular order? please post some **code** that demonstrates what you are having an issue with - i.e the "script" that is "ruined" (note: firefox does no such thing, only **chrum** does

Comment: Done, added code sample. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `in Chrome and Firefox they get logged alphabetically` no ... not firefox ... chrome is the outlier, bad bad chrome :p if you see firefox do anything different, perhaps your firefox is **old**' - actually, firefox is a lot more complex - it's almost random

Comment: one thing to learn from this ... object keys have no order - never rely on it

Answer (score 1):

Although storage has a `length` property and you can get the key for indexes `0` through `length - 1`, it is **not** an array and it has no defined order. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface):

> The `key(n)` method must return the name of the *n*th key in the list. **The order of keys is user-agent defined**, but must be consistent within an object so long as the number of keys doesn't change. (Thus, **adding or removing a key may change the order of the keys...**

*(my emphasis)*

If you want a defined order, store an array in storage rather than storing individual entries, via JSON:

On page load / when reading from storage, get the array from storage:

```
entries = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("entries") || "[]");
```

Note that if `"entries"` isn't in `sessionStorage`, `getItem` will return `null`, so we provide a default of `"[]"` for `JSON.parse` to parse. (There are lots of ways to skin that cat, this is just one of them.)

When you want to save to storage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(entries));
```

That way, the entries are in the order **you** define (the order of the array).

---

Re your edit: `entries` would be an array of objects for your products.